# Apache Camel Rest endpoint to Activemq/JMS enpoint working example

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, jms

I have a REST web service setup using a local IIS server on port 443, and wants to use Apache Camel to send some traffic coming from this REST service to a local Activemq broker on port 8443. So it will be from a REST endpoint to a JMS endpoint.

I am trying to find an working example online on what should I do here, but I can only find ways of making a REST API using Camel. Is there a working example on from REST endpoint to a JMS endpoint?

Comment: what do you mean when you say "send some traffic coming from this REST"? You could get the camel somehow scheduled for polling your REST, is this what you want?

Comment: That certainly can be a possibility, is there an example that I can look at?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of REST polling in camel [docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/http4-component.html#_sample_with_scheduled_poll), it uses a simple timer to get it scheduled. You may want to implement more complicate schedule that will be more relevant in your case, e.g to poll the REST endpoint when some custom event has occurred.